# phonegap parsing incoming data to application

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

Using PhoneGap I am opening an application on Android from a link in an email using an intent specified in the Manifest file. This is working fine.

What I need to do now is parse in some data to the application that is opened, the data I am retrieving from the URL query params, this is working fine I am reading the URL that is clicked in the email within the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method thus:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
System.out.println("- start intent -");
final Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null && intent.getDataString() != null){
    System.out.println("- data string:"+intent.getDataString());
    String url = intent.getDataString();
    this.sendJavascript("testMethod('"+url+"');");
    System.out.println("- finished method call");
}
```

If you look at the code above the system outs are all output as expected and the data string is exactly as expected but the testMethod(url), which is in my index.js file, never gets called.
Even when I do a simple method thus

```
function testMethod(url){
            alert("************************ alert");
            console.log("******************** log")
            console.warn("******************** warn")
            console.info("******************** info")
            console.error("******************** error")
 }
```

None of the console calls or the alert are made.
So to me it seems that the sendJavascript method is not being executed or called.
**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could not get this to function at all. What I am trying to acheive is pass a value in when the application is loaded from a URL. I acheived this by changing the URL if there is an intent and adding query parameters to the loadUrl. Then in the index.js I have checked for window.location.search and then called an extra function if a specific query param is found like this.

```
        if(intent != null && intent.getDataString() != null){
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html?register=true");
    }
    else{
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

Then in the Javascript

```
 if(window.location.search === "?register=true"){
        handleOpenURL("my/url");
    }
```